# JQuery tablesorter custom parser to all headers?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm currently working with a tablesorter table in which I need to use a custom parser for each header.  I'd like to know if there's an easy way to do this, such as:

```
table.tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            0-20: { 
                sorter:'CareerLast' 
            }, 

        } 
    });
```

I know that the above code doesn't work, but I'm just wondering if there's a more readable way of applying the custom parser, other than manually placing it on each column by index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think you have three choices:

1. Define each header, 0 through 20 in the initialization options.

   ```
   header : {
       0 : { sorter : 'CareerLast' },
       1 : { sorter : 'CareerLast' },
       2 : { sorter : 'CareerLast' },
       // etc
       20 : { sorter : 'CareerLast' }
   }
   ```
2. Use the meta data plugin and add the sorter definition in the header class:

   ```
   // untested, but I think this will work
   $('table').find('thead th').addClass("{sorter:'CareerLast'}");
   $('table').tablesorter();
   ```
3. Try out my [forked version of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html) and just add the sorter as a class name

   ```
   $('table').find('thead th').addClass('sorter-CareerLast');
   $('table').tablesorter();
   ```

Comment: I went with option 3.  Nice work on the add-on; it made my life much easier!

Comment: Option #2 worked for me, although I needed to add single quotes around 'CareerLast'.

Answer (score 0):

return true from 'is' in addParser

eg: this parser assigns 'N/A' a value of -1 

`$.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'num-with-na',
        is: function(s) {
            //always use this
            return true;
        },
        format: function(n){
            return n === 'N/A' ? -1 : n;
        },
        type: 'numeric'
    });`

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the original question a bit more?

Comment: the op wanted to apply a custom parser to all columns in a table without individually adding it to each column ( like Mottie's #1). This is simple way to do it without adding classes