# custom sort order in tablesorter - jquery

Tags: tablesorter

I do use tablesorter (https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html)
To sort my HTML tables.

I have one sorting I cannot find howtoo. ie.

- (4)
- (dns)
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 5
- dns

is to be sorted as:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- (4)
- 5
- (dns)
- dns

in short: the () are to be ignored and numeric sort, numeric first then alphabetical.

I have seen how to replace characters, (doesn't work as "empty" as some rank too)
The parsers I have seen thusfar require me to create per header and known value to be replaced.
ie:

```
    $.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    id: 'nummeriek', 
    is: function(s) { 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.toLowerCase().replace('dns',999).replace('(dns)',999).replace('(4)',4); 
    }, 
    type: 'numeric' 
}); 

$('.tablesorter').tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            6: { 
                sorter:'nummeriek' 
            } 
        } 
});
```

If I have to do this for every possible table content I end up creating hundreds of replace() statements. as I have scores from 1 to 100 Thus (1) to (100) is possible too...

There must be an easier way. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The default `digit` parser "assumes" that numbers wrapped in parentheses are negative; this is a common method of indicating a negative number in accounting ([ref](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/1875)).

To get around this, you will need to slightly modify the parser ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/448/))

```
$(function() {
  $.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'nummeriek',
    is: function(s) {
      return false;
    },
    format: function(str) {
      // format your data for normalization
      var s = str.replace(/[()]/g, ""),
        n = parseFloat(s);
      return !isNaN(n) && isFinite(n) ? n : s;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
  });

  $('.tablesorter').tablesorter({
    headers: {
      0: {
        sorter: 'nummeriek'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Note: this parser *always* returns a non-numeric string without parentheses, e.g. "(dns)" will become "dns". I kept it this way so the "(dns)" entries will sort as if they are "dns".

Comment: Now that is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: The one thing I am left with is the amount of headers involved. As this is a one column table, i can easlily also have a 2, 8, 12 a variable amount of columns. I tried with the addClass methods I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014962/jquery-tablesorter-custom-parser-to-all-headers but I cannot get it to work for all columns.. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed your question. In the `headers` option you can use a jQuery selector to target the column instead of a zero-based index - `headers: { '.nummeriek': { sorter: 'nummeriek' } }` ([example](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html)). Or, add a `sorter-nummeriek` class to each column that needs it .